# Перевод из системы координат сцены(mapToScene()) в систему координат представления

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

Нужно узнать как меняются координаты точки не на сцене(scene()),а в системе представления изменения масштаба скроллингом мыши. Я использую метод mapFromScene(), но результат не тот.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsLineItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QRectF
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.resize(1000, 600)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        zoomInFactor = 1.15
        zoomOutFactor = 1 / zoomInFactor

        oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            zoomFactor = zoomInFactor
        else:
            zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
        self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)

        newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        delta = newPos - oldPos
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())


        self.pop = event.pos()
        start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapFromScene(self.pop))
        end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapFromScene(event.pos()))
        for point in (start, end):
            print("x", point.x(), "y", point.y())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self._start = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        od_start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self._start))
        od_end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))

        start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self._start))
        end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))

        self.scene().addItem(
            QGraphicsLineItem(QtCore.QLineF(od_start, od_end)))
        for point in (start, end):
            text = self.scene().addSimpleText(
                '(%d, %d)' % (point.x(), point.y()))
            text.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
            text.setPos(point)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.resize(1000, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Das")
        self.w = GraphicsView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)
        self.penWidth = 10
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.drawLine()

    def drawLine(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 20
        el = SimpleItem(self.penWidth, self.x, self.y)
        self.w.scene().addItem(el)


class SimpleItem(QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, width, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.penWidth = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresTransformations)

    def boundingRect(self):
        self.p = QRectF(-self.penWidth/2, -self.penWidth/2, self.penWidth, self.penWidth)
        return self.p

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(10)
        pen.setCosmetic(True)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawPoint(self.x, self.y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте, может это то что вам нужно.
По сути, я только переопределил класс `QGraphicsScene`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsLineItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QRectF
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class SimpleItem(QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, width, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.penWidth = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresTransformations)

    def boundingRect(self):
        self.p = QRectF(-self.penWidth/2, -self.penWidth/2, self.penWidth, self.penWidth)
        return self.p

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(3)                                            # - (10)
        pen.setCosmetic(True)
        painter.setPen(pen)
#        painter.drawPoint(self.x, self.y)
        painter.drawEllipse(QtCore.QPointF(), 12, 12)              # +


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

class GraphicsScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setSceneRect(-200, -200, 400, 400)  

    # Рисует фон сцены, используя painter, до того, как будут нарисованы 
    # какие-либо элементы и передний план. Все рисование выполняется в координатах сцены. 
    # Параметр rect - это открытый прямоугольник.
    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        painter.setPen(QPen(QtCore.Qt.green, 3)) 
        painter.drawRect(self.sceneRect())

        painter.setPen(QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 3))
        painter.drawText(0, 0, '0')           
        painter.drawText(-200, -200, '-200')
        painter.drawText(200, 200, '200')

# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

#        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self))                  # ---
#        self.resize(1000, 600)                                         # ---
        self.setScene(GraphicsScene())                                  # +++  !!!     

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        zoomInFactor = 1.15
        zoomOutFactor = 1 / zoomInFactor

        oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            zoomFactor = zoomInFactor
        else:
            zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
        self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)

        newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        delta = newPos - oldPos
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())


        self.pop = event.pos()
        start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapFromScene(self.pop))
        end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapFromScene(event.pos()))
        for point in (start, end):
            print("x", point.x(), "y", point.y())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self._start = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        od_start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self._start))
        od_end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))

        start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self._start))
        end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))

        self.scene().addItem(
            QGraphicsLineItem(QtCore.QLineF(od_start, od_end)))
        for point in (start, end):
            text = self.scene().addSimpleText(
                '(%d, %d)' % (point.x(), point.y()))
            text.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
            text.setPos(point)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
#        self.resize(1000, 600)
        self.resize(600, 600)                                     # +
        self.setWindowTitle("Das")
        self.w = GraphicsView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)
        self.penWidth = 10
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.drawLine()

    def drawLine(self):
        self.x = 0     # 10
        self.y = 0     # 20
        el = SimpleItem(self.penWidth, self.x, self.y)
        self.w.scene().addItem(el)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне требуется перевести из "моей" системы координат в систему координат сцены,но это делает сцена автоматически, как я понял. Мне же нужно найти метод или функцию для обратного преобразования,то есть из системы координат сцены в "мою" систему координат.